# Is there a way to chain multiple WHERE statements together without switching to AND in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a large application using a Neo4j database. There are dozens of methods that hold Cypher queries. In order to remove the duplicate code that would exist if each method stored its own complete query, I have created private methods that build small commonly used chunks of a query. For example, a method like:

```
MatchNodesWithLabel(string label)
```

would return a partial query like:

```
MATCH (node:label)
```

These method calls are then followed by methods that add `WHERE` or `RETURN` statements to build a full query. This is a small example, there are methods that match and filter whole sets of nodes and relations.

The problem arises when multiple `WHERE` statements need to be chained together. Cypher doesn't allow a `WHERE` statement to follow a `WHERE` statement:

```
// Invalid
MATCH (node)
WHERE node:label
WHERE node.property = value
...
```

so any method past the first `WHERE` must insert an `AND` statement instead:

```
// Valid
MATCH (node)
WHERE node:label
AND node.property = value
AND ...
```

This creates a method ordering problem, where certain methods can not be used after others. A method that inserts a `WHERE` statement (a `Where()` method) must precede an `And()` method. `Where()` methods then can't be used after an `And()` method, and `And()` methods can't be used before `Where()` methods.

Here are some possible (but ultimately broken) solutions I've come up with to solve this ordering problem:

1. Duplicate every `Where()` method into an equivalent `AndWhere()` method that does the same filtering, but uses `AND` instead of `WHERE`. Then in the calling code, use one `Where()` method first, and `AndWhere()` methods thereafter.

   - This is not an acceptable solution because of code duplication, and because it complicates the calling code. It just moves the method ordering problem to the calling code, instead of solving the problem. I want to be able to add a `Where()` call whenever I want, without thinking about how my methods are ordered
2. Add a `WHERE true` statement before all the other calls, then make every `Where()` method insert an `AND` statement.

   - This only works if the methods in the calling code are specifically ordered. All `MATCH` methods have to precede the `WHERE true`, otherwise you could end up with a Cypher query like:

     `MATCH (node)
     WHERE true
     AND node:type
     MATCH (somethingElse)
     AND somethingElse.property = value`

     which is invalid since `AND` follows a `MATCH` without a `WHERE`. So once again the responsibility of method ordering has moved to the calling code. With this solution, you have to manually add a `WHERE true` every time you start a new series of filtering calls.
3. Parse the existing query to determine whether a `WHERE` or an `AND` should be used at the start of every `Where()` method.

   - This seems ok at first, all you have to do is a check like `existingQuery.Contains("WHERE")` and if its true, insert `AND` instead. However this has the same problem as #2. If a new `MATCH` statement is inserted, the check will still return true, but the query won't be in a state where an `AND` is a valid statement. So you'd have to parse further back in the query, checking for `MATCH` and `WHERE` statements, and you'd have to keep track of the order they occurred in, etc... This is far too complicated.

Is some Neo4j syntax that allows a `WHERE` to be inserted anywhere, or a query building solution that I haven't some across?

Answer (score 4):

Add a `WITH *` before every `WHERE` statement.

`WITH *` will carry over all named Cypher identifiers already in the query into what is essentially a new query.

So the query will end up looking like:

```
MATCH (node)
WITH *
WHERE ...
WITH *
WHERE ...
MATCH (somethingElse)
WITH *
WHERE ...
```

etc.

This allows a `WHERE` to be inserted anywhere in a query.

So every `Where()` method will insert `WITH * WHERE` instead of just `WHERE` or `AND`.

**Important note:** This will slow down the query. Every `WITH` is a projection and projections aren't free. In my testing a query using `WITH * WHERE` is 30% - 50% slower than the equivalent `WHERE ... AND` query.

This is definitely an ugly solution. Hopefully a better solution exists, one that is just as fast as a `WHERE ... AND` query and doesn't clutter the query text, but this solution works as long as speed and query readability are acceptable sacrifices.

**EDIT:** I've discovered that this solution also ignores indexes in the `WHERE` statements! This makes the performance of these queries unacceptably slow for large data sets. I'd strongly advise against using this trick and instead sacrifice some code readability or code duplication for decent performance.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can have 2 collections: say `matches` and `wheres`. Your MatchX() and WhereY() methods can append appropriate data to their respective collections. When you are ready to submit your query, you can generate the `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses from the data in those collections.